# pyspark hive - Insert NULL as DB null through text file

Tags: pyspark, hive, null, dbnull

While inserting text file from **pyspark** shell to **hive** table.

NULL values treating as string in table.

If i query hive table, records can be retried only with filter condition `= 'NULL'` rather than `is null`.

Can any one suggest how to insert data as DB NULLS in table

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include a [mcve] of the code that causes the inserts. See [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if your spark dataframe is having null or None.
And while writing to the hive table set the nullValue option as

```
df.write.option('nullValue', None).saveAsTable(path)
```

This will solve your issue.